# Unresolved MPI Fortran symbols when compiling p3dfft driver

Tags: c, mpi, fftw

I have been getting the following error when I try to compile the driver p3dfft program. What should I do to avoid this error?

```
latish@latish-Aspire-E5-573G:~/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/sample/C$ mpicc  -g -O2 -lmpi_f90 -o test_sine_c.x driver_sine.o ../../build/libp3dfft.a /usr/local//lib/libfftw3.a   -lgfortran -lmpichf90 -lm
../../build/libp3dfft.a(module.o): In function `ztran_f_same_many':
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/ftran.F90:819: undefined reference to `mpi_abort_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/ftran.F90:794: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/ftran.F90:816: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/ftran.F90:803: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/ftran.F90:812: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
../../build/libp3dfft.a(module.o): In function `ztran_b_same_many':
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/btran.F90:300: undefined reference to `mpi_abort_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/btran.F90:275: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/btran.F90:297: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/btran.F90:284: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/btran.F90:293: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
../../build/libp3dfft.a(module.o): In function `fcomm2_many':
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:52: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:69: undefined reference to `mpi_alltoallv_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:72: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:74: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:79: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
../../build/libp3dfft.a(module.o): In function `fcomm2':
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:213: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:256: undefined reference to `mpi_alltoallv_'
/home/latish/btp/p3dfft-2.7.5/build/fcomm2.F90:257: undefined reference to `mpi_wtime_'


collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't use use `mpifort` instead of `mpicc` as the linker ?
you are obviously linking a Fortran app.

an other option is to try the `-lmpi_f90` option **after** the `fftw` libs

Comment: It's a C program that's why I am using mpicc and thank you that second part helped me, linking mpi_f90 after fftw libs is not giving me error

Comment: you might also consider building `p3dfft` *without* the Fortran bindings. also, if you found my initial answer helpful, please consider accepting it.